# How to get more precision for float in C++

Tags: c++

As float numbers have a range until `3.4*10^38`. I want to extract 10 digits from the beginning.

For example:

If `MyNumber = 3882927188899`

Then my desired output will be `3882927188`.

How to do that?

Comment: An IEEE 754 float doesn't have 10 digits to extract.

Comment: Switch to `double` precision if you need more.

Comment: what did you try and where it went wrong?

Comment: did you miss some part in the C++ book? there definitely were some information about `double` and `long double`

Answer (score -2):

This will do the job.

```
template <class T>
int numDigits(T number)
{
    int digits = 0;
    if (number < 0) digits = 1; // remove this line if '-' counts as a digit
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        digits++;
    }
    return digits;
} 

int getDigits(float number, int numberOfDigits){
    return floor(number / pow(10, numDigits(number) - numberOfDigits));
}
```

Comment: This will, at best, produce a number whose low-order digits are noise. You can't recover precision that wasn't there to begin with.

Comment: This isn't even c++.

Comment: yo @PeteBecker he's asking how he could get the first x digits of a number

Comment: @obwan02 -- yes, that's what he's asking. Can't be done: you can't get more precision than the type stores.